# When adding an existing item with "Add as Link", this file is not compiled in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When adding an existing item with "Add as Link", this file is not compiled in VS2015 ?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's supported.

Comment: I can't seem to find <kbd>Add as Link</kbd> at all. In my case I just need to add a shortcut to a file, but I don't need it to be compiled at all.

Comment: Relevant link https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/147

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, this is not yet supported. I contacted the engineering owners of this feature and they are investigating what it would take to support this.

You can manually add a "linked" file in the `project.json` file:

```
{
    ... other stuff ...

    "compile": [
        "../path/to/somewhere.cs",
        "../../another/path/to/file.cs",
        "../../use/globbing/**/*.cs"
    ],

    ... other stuff ...
}
```

The schema for the file is available here: https://github.com/SchemaStore/schemastore/blob/master/src/schemas/json/project.json#L98-L119

And in Visual Studio while editing a `project.json` file you'll see this same schema in Intellisense.

Comment: This will not work always in case the "somewhere.cs" file depends on code in the main project, the build fails. I guess we have to wait until this is really supported.

Comment: @Stef can you clarify what you mean by "depends on code in the main project"? If it depends on code that isn't in the "current" project then you'll need to import those files as well. That should be no different than in other project types how when you pull in one file, you have to pull in whatever else is depends on.

Comment: Another question, why is are the .cs file locations separated by a ; ?

Why not use an array like "code" : [ "../path/*.cs", "../path2/*.cs" ] ?

Comment: @Stef you know, that's a great question. If you'd like, please log a bug on https://github.com/aspnet/XRE/issues.

Comment: According to David, this should be supported. See this issue here on github: https://github.com/aspnet/XRE/issues/1026#issuecomment-73465978

Comment: I now got the warning that 'code' is deprecated, and 'compile' should be used.

Comment: @Geerten thanks I updated the answer to reflect the most recent schema.

Comment: Now it's `buildOptions: { compile ['path1', 'path2' ... 'pathn'] }`.

Answer (score 0):

Use your <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and drag the file where ever you want.