# How does a "stand alone" class file work?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm looking into the source code of [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer) and found something interesting. From its dev branch, you can see there is a stand alone class file named [HttpClientSlim](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/tree/dev/test/shared) in `/test/shared` folder which doesn't belong to any project. And it's used in a few projects. I cloned the source code, the solution explorer looks like

[image: this]

how does it compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you attempt to add an existing item to a project there is a small dropdown next to the "Add" button which allows you to add as a link.

This means that if you want a class included in multiple projects you can keep the actual source file in one place, but "link it in" to multiple projects.

It saves copy/pasteing code, but the project compiles it into the binary as if it were local.

[image]

Note that for users of VS2015, you may need to manually edit `project.json` to get the same functionality, this is described in more detail in this Q/A:
[When adding an existing item with "Add as Link", this file is not compiled in VS2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175451/when-adding-an-existing-item-with-add-as-link-this-file-is-not-compiled-in-vs)

Comment: Why I don't see any dropdown next to the "Add" button in VS2015 community?

Comment: @DannyChen its only when you choose "Add existing item". Obviously if you choose "Add new item" then you cannot link to an existing file. Ive updated with a screenshot.

Comment: And I just noticed my description made it out to be the other way. Sorry about that

Comment: I know the reason, when I open a windows console application, I see the option like your screenshot. But for a .net core application, there is no such an option.

Comment: But the projects of Kestrel are .net core applications. I tried, no such a option. And even there is, something in the `.xproj` file should tell. I checked the project file and found nothing.

Comment: @DannyChen Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/28175451/247702, you might need to manually edit `project.json`.

Comment: @Stijn Got it in `/compile/include` section. Actually I checked `project.json` before asking this question, but I missed it uncarefully!

Comment: @Jamiec Can you edit the answer according to Stijn's comment so that others can find the reason easily? Thanks.

Comment: Ill edit in a link to that q/a - no point repeating good info onsite